# How does a block with curly braces and parentheses work?

Tags: swift

```
let loginRegisterButton:UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.backgroundColor = .white
    button.setTitle("Register", for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    return button
}()
```

is this variable or function , why does it return value? why do we call it? it does not work without `parenthesis`,why?

Answer (score 16):

This is a *closure* created and used in the same spot. You use it for initialization when you cannot put everything in a single expression. This feature is helpful when creating read-only (`let`, as opposed to `var`) fields.

In the case above, the code creates a button, and then performs additional configuration on it before returning the result. This is a good way to move code from `init` into code blocks near the place of initialization.

One way to visualize what's going on is to think of a named function that does the same thing:

```
func makeWhiteButton() -> UIButton {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.White
    button.setTitle("Register", for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    return button
}
```

Now you can use it in an initializer

```
let loginRegisterButton:UIButton = makeWhiteButton()
```

The code from your post does the same thing with an anonymous "closure" function. The parentheses after the closure block are there for the same reason as the parentheses after `makeWhiteButton` above.

Comment: @Ninja13 You are welcome! If you do not need further help, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey check mark next to it. This would let others know that your problem is solved, and earn you a new badge on Stack Overflow.